# Element is selected but not clicked in selenium

Tags: css, selenium

`<a class="btn button-action-bar" href="javascript:upload();">Upload files...</a>`

I identify the Upload button with `CSS` Selector `a[href*='javascript:upload();']`

When the script is running, Upload button is selected but not clicked . 
Tried with `click()`, `sendkeysReturn()`,`sendKeysEnter()`

(sometimes clicking the button twice works, but not always)

Comment: Had similar issues with a dropdown list item. Does your *Upload* button have a parent node? Have you tried clicking that node? Or a parent of a parent, if such exists.

Comment: No it doesn't have a parent node

Comment: How about `Actions` object? `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("javascript:upload();"))).click().build().perform();`

Comment: Why do you have the asterix in the attribute `href*`?

Comment: Can you share the link of the page ?

Comment: just to match i used *. Even if * is removed , its not working. Button is selected but not clicked

Comment: Link cannot be shared due to security reasons